# Результат не выводится в консоль

Tags: java, массивы, консоль

Решать ничего **не** надо! Зато объясните, почему результат в консоль не выводится??

```
import static java.lang.System.out;
import java.util.Arrays;

class Ideone{
public static void main (String[] args){
          int[] arr={1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
          task(arr);
         }
     public static String task(int[] array) {
                if (array.length <= 2) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Нечего менять");
                }
                for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i += 2) {
                    array[i] = array[i] + array[i + 1];
                    array[i + 1] = array[i] - array[i + 1];
                    array[i] = array[i] - array[i + 1];
                }
                return ("Массив:"+Arrays.toString(array));
}}
```

(Задача: В заданном одномерном массиве поменять местами соседние элементы, стоящие на четных местах, с элементами, стоящими на нечетных)

Comment: Так Вы в `main` не вывели на печать ничего.

Comment: Встречный вопрос – а почему результат должен выводиться в консоль?

Comment: мне нужно понять как работает цикл)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод `task(arr);` хоть и возвращает строку, но не выводит её.Стоит написать `System.out.println(task(arr));`, тогда в консоль выведет возвращаемую методом `task()` строку.

Comment: А можно просто `out.println(task(arr));`, коль уж автор использует статический импорт `import static java.lang.System.out;`.